# Can this hinge loss be modified for more than one pair?

Tags: ranking, loss-functions

```
L = max{0, M − cosine(q, a+) + cosine(q, a−)}
```

This is the loss function described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04108.pdf. This takes the ground truth and compares it with a negative example. How can I modify this for multiple negative examples?